# Group law in universal central extension of Thompson's group T

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology, universal-property

I'm having some troubles with universal central extensions and associated cocycles; in particular, I want to understand the group law of the universal central extension of the Thompson's group $T$.

Let us consider the universal central extension $E$ of the Thompson's group $T$; I know that it is possible to describe $E$ as the set $H_2(G; \mathbb{Z}) \times T$ with the group law defined in the following way $$(a,t)\cdot (a',t')=(a+_{H_2(G)}a'+_{H_2(G)} \phi(t,t'), t \cdot_Tt'),$$
where $\phi \in C^2(T; H_2(T; \mathbb{Z}))$ is the 2-cocycle associated to the extension $E$ (we denote its cohomology class by $[\phi]$), and is characterized by the following universal property: for any abelian group $A$ and for any $v \in H^2(T;A)$ there is a unique $f:H_2(T; \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow A$ such that $v=H^2(T,f)[\phi]$ (here we are using that since $T$ is perfect we have a universal coefficient isomorphism $H^2(T;A) \simeq Hom(H_2(T; \mathbb{Z}), A)$).

I know that $H^2(T; \mathbb{Z}) \simeq \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ and is generated by the
Euler class $eu$ and a certain class $\alpha$, which can be described explicitely in terms of the Godbillon-Vey cocycle (see https://eudml.org/doc/140083, Corollary 4.5). Moreover, I know that also $H_2(T; \mathbb{Z})\simeq \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ by the universal coefficient isomorphism above.

I want to understand why the cocycle $\phi$ associated to the universal central extension $E$ is $(t,t') \rightarrow (Eu(t,t'), A(t,t'))$, where $A$ is a 2-cocycle representing the class $\alpha$. Also references are appreciated.

Comment: What's a reference for the given description of $H_2(T,\mathbf{Z})$?

Comment: @YCor "Sur un grup remarquable de diffeomorphisme di cercle", Ghys and Sergiescu (I've come across the statement studing "The spectrum of simplicial volume", by Heuer and Loeh, https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.04539,  Theorem 5.5)

Comment: I've looked into the Ghys-Sergiescu paper (available [here](https://eudml.org/doc/140083)), the 2-cocycle $2\alpha$ seems to be related to the "Godbillon-Vey class", and more precisely to a discretized version of the "Bott-Thurston 2-cocycle". The 2-cocycle is explicitly computed in Thm E (Cor. 4.5). The interpretation of the corresponding central extension is maybe implicit but (at the moment) beyond my understanding.

Comment: Yes, I knew the description of $2 \alpha$ in terms of the Godbillon-Vey cocycle, but I think that in order to compute the cocycle associated to the universal central extension it should be enough knowing that $\alpha$ and the Euler cocycle generate $H^2(T; \mathbb{Z}$ (but still, I don't know how to make it explicit).

Comment: This is part of the context which is useful in order to answer the question...!

Comment: Ok, I will add it to the question!

Comment: I do not understand why are you asking this question here. Do you think that MO users know the paper better than the authors?

Comment: At this point I'm not sure I understand the question, and whether the result just follows formally passing from $H_2$ to $H^2$ in some standard way.

Comment: Perhaps Section 6.6 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.0559.pdf helps?